# Browser Sync Not Working Permissions Issue

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, sublimetext3, browser-sync

Browser Sync is not launching live server after installing node/npm as a root user. Backstory: I tried installing Browser Sync npm to no avail then i installed the npm package and got a permissions error so i installed via the root and it installed. I switched to my regular user acct and tried to launch browser sync to no avail i assumed it would run b/c npm or node was a globe install. While in my regular user account, i ran `npm install -g browser-sync`
in the terminal again, however im still having permissions issues.

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync

I'm using sublime 3 on a mac. Also, i tried using browser sync w/o installing npm to no avail any suggestions would be appreciated, even another tool recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the golbal insall directory using npm config command.

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

More info: http://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/installing/a-note-on-permissions.html

Comment: Thanks. That worked. However, I'm still unable to run Browser Sync. After following the 3rd instruction on https://www.browsersync.io/ to input browser-sync start --server --files "css/*.css"
the local host server is created and opens a 3000 webpage that renders the text cannot GET. The file i'm trying to launch is.../ index.html so im not sure why im getting this error. Do you know why?

Comment: I got it to work but it seems like in order for you to use browser sync you have to open the terminal and cd to where you're working in and i dont want to do that everytime...